# Why google speech_v1p1beta1 output only shows the last word?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I am using the code below to transcribe an audio file. When the process is completed, I only get the last word.

I have tried both flac and wav files and made sure the files are in my bucket.
Also verified service account is google is working fine. But can't figure out why I am only getting the last word.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Google Cloud Speech API sample that demonstrates enhanced models
and recognition metadata.
Example usage:
    python diarization.py
"""

import argparse
import io



def transcribe_file_with_diarization():
    """Transcribe the given audio file synchronously with diarization."""
    # [START speech_transcribe_diarization_beta]
    from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
    client = speech.SpeechClient()


audio = speech.types.RecognitionAudio(uri="gs://MYBUCKET/MYAudiofile")

config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=8000,
    language_code='en-US',
    enable_speaker_diarization=True,
    diarization_speaker_count=2)

print('Waiting for operation to complete...')
response = client.recognize(config, audio)

# The transcript within each result is separate and sequential per result.
# However, the words list within an alternative includes all the words
# from all the results thus far. Thus, to get all the words with speaker
# tags, you only have to take the words list from the last result:
result = response.results[-1]

words_info = result.alternatives[0].words

# Printing out the output:
for word_info in words_info:
    print("word: '{}', speaker_tag: {}".format(word_info.word,
                                               word_info.speaker_tag))
# [END speech_transcribe_diarization_beta]



if __name__ == '__main__':

    transcribe_file_with_diarization()
```

RESULTS is shown here after running the code:

python diarazation.py

```
Waiting for operation to complete...
word: 'bye', speaker_tag: 0
```